# "Generalized arrows" and proc notation?

Tags: haskell, ghc, arrows, category-abstractions

When learning about `Control.Arrow` and Haskell's built-in `proc` notation, I had the idea that this language might prove very useful as an eDSL for general monoidal categories (using `***` for tensor and `>>>` for composition), if only the `Arrow` typeclass were generalized to allow a general `tens :: * -> * -> *` operation rather than `Arrow`'s `(,) : * -> * -> *`.

After doing some research, I found [`GArrows`](http://www.megacz.com/berkeley/garrows/), which seem to fit my needs. However, the linked `Garrow` typeclass comes bundled with the so-called "HetMet" GHC extensions, and support for other features that (for the time being, anyway), I don't have much use for, such as "modal types".

Given that I would like to be able to use such a `GArrow` typeclass without having to install non-standard GHC extensions:

1. Is there an actual (somewhat standardized) library on Hackage that meets my needs for such a generalized arrow typeclass?
2. Given such a library, is there any way to use such a `GArrow` type class with a "generalized `proc`" notation without having to cook up my own GHC extension? (With `RebindableSyntax` perhaps?)

Note: Also, I'm fine with using quasiquotation for a generalized `proc` notation. So perhaps it wouldn't be too difficult to modify something like [this](https://github.com/pepeiborra/arrowp) to suit my needs.

Comment: Have you found anything suitable in the meantime, or an alternative approach? In case I haven't made it clear enough yet: I'm very interested in this too, both the category stuff in general but also the music application in particular. If I can help in some way, don't hesitate to tap me on Github. Maybe we can fork `constrained-categories` if it helps.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I've been working on this a bit on and off. The biggest issue for me so far has been getting a nice type class hierarchy for different kinds of monoidal categories. To be completely general, I want to have a category typeclass like [this](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/4736), which I don't think is very easy to accomplish in Haskell without a ton of compiler extensions.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/leftaroundabout/746cfa44fdf1a79a645507e66780eba3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've wondered about that before, too. But – `proc` notation is so widely considered a silly oddball that there's probably not much interest in generalisation either (though I daresay this is what would make it actually useful!)

However, it's actually not *necessary* to have special syntax. The primary reference that must be named here is Conal Elliott's work on [compiling lambda notation to bicartesian closed categories](http://conal.net/blog/posts/overloading-lambda). Which I thought would have caught on in the Haskell community some time by now, but somehow hasn't. It is available as a GHC plugin, at any rate.

Even that isn't always needed. For some category combinators, you can just wrap a value that's universally quantified in the argument, and treat that as a pseudo-return-value. I call those [`Agent` in constrained-categories](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.0.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html#t:HasAgent); not sure if that's usable for your application, at any rate several things you'd do with arrow-like categories [can be done](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html#g:6). (In constrained-categories, the tensor product is fixed to `(,)`, however, so probably not what you want. Although, could you explain what tensor product you need?)

Comment: I'm currently working on a library for preforming various transformations (e.x. translations, transpositions, retrograde inversion, etc...) on abstract representations of musical scores. I haven't settled on the data type to use for this yet, but I'm pretty sure I need something more general than `(,)`. Or at least I think it would be nicer with something more general. (I'm thinking of using some variation on sized vectors of this, since e.x. I need to keep track on how many lines there are in a score, and I would like to be able to express this at the type level)

Comment: So, I think `(,)` actually would work for my particular application, in that `a` is isomorphic to `Vec 1 a`, `(a,a)` is isomorphic to `Vec 2 a`, `((a,a),a)` isomorphic to `Vec 3 a` and so on. But this doesn't seem as clean as using typed vectors, and I'd also like to potentially consider other monoidal categories in the future.

Comment: Yeah. The reason I stayed with `(,)` in constrained-categories is that **a)** in many interesting categories, this can indeed be used just fine (I suspect this could somehow be explained with the Yoneda lemma) and **b)** it helps type inference. But yeah, proper associativity of the tensor product would certainly be nice conceptually; it would actually make type inference more difficult though.