# Constrained Arrow do notation

Tags: haskell

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}
```

Given some constraint `Foo`, I would like to use the rebindable arrow do-notation in `FooArrow`s: where types satisfy `Foo`. We can only lift arrows between `Foo` types and we can only tensor them using `first` if they are `foo` types.

```hs
class FooArrow hom where
  arr :: (Foo a) => (a -> b) -> hom a b
  (>>>) :: (Foo a, Foo b, Foo c) => hom a b -> hom b c -> hom a c
  first :: (Foo a, Foo b, Foo c) => hom a b -> hom (a, c) (b, c)

returnA :: (FooArrow hom, Foo a) => hom a a
returnA = arr (\a -> a)
```

And everything compiles fine until here. However, when actually using the notation, the compiler will complain that `• Could not deduce (Foo b1) arising from a use of ‘first’`, even in contexts where I think I have already provided all of the `Foo` constraints.

```hs
swap :: (FooArrow hom, Foo a, Foo b) => hom (a,b) (b,a)
swap = proc (a , b) ->
    returnA -< (b, a)

class Foo a where
instance Foo () where
instance (Foo a, Foo b) => Foo (a , b) where
```

Why am I getting this error? Am I missing something to make this work? Is it possible at all to get constrained arrow do-notation?

Comment: Potentially related, although a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56620644/generalized-arrows-and-proc-notation

Comment: It was originally one of my aims with [constrained-categories](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories) to rebind arrow syntax, but I never actually got to that point – created the concepts of `Agent`s instead, which rather emulate Conal Elliott's _compiling to categories_ approach.

Answer (score 5):

Rebindable syntax for arrows is something that's been in [feature-limbo for a long time](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/7828).  Indeed, the linked ticket details almost exactly your problem, and it's from 2013.  I mean, technically, rebindable syntax for arrows exists, but as it says [in the documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/rebindable_syntax.html#extension-RebindableSyntax): "the types of these functions must match the Prelude types very closely. Details are in flux; if you want to use this, ask!"

I feel obligated to point out that that 8 year-old ticket does have activity from a year and a half ago that says the work is in progress.  But, if you need a solution now, I think the only way you can proceed with what you're trying to do is to use a GHC extension or pre-processor.  Maybe Paterson's original [arrowp](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arrowp) pre-processor could work for your needs, but a search on hackage also reveals (the somewhat newer) [arrowp-qq](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arrowp-qq), which could be another option to look into.